# I can't use a custom theme on a network account

Tags: windows-7, networking, themes, users

I'm an administrator for the computer I use, but I'm using a network account. I can set custom themes (non-Microsoft, I mean) on my local account but not on the network account. It's the same machine, just different accounts/domains. I tried to repatch the files from the network account, but it says they're already patched.

Any ideas why this won't work? The themes don't show up in the Personalize menu, and I can't just double click the .theme file from the Themes folder in Windows 7 Pro.

This is the theme I'm trying to use, by the way: http://fediafedia.deviantart.com/art/Windows-8-VS-for-Win7-258514188?q=boost%3Apopular%20windows%208%20theme&qo=0

Tried repatching the files, still nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. For some reason I had to copy and paste the files from my network account. Not sure what the difference is, but that fixed it.

Comment: The difference is who owns the files. If you copy as Acct A and paste into Acct B's folder Acct A still owns them.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your network account (Domain Account), you may or may not do this.

There are numerous reason why a Domain account will not allow this.  The biggest one is obviously Group Policy, which can explicitly disable themes.

The Shell Theme services also needs to be running, but that requires admin privs. Use your local Admin Credentials to check these settings.

Comment: I could use custom themes on my old network account, on another computer, so could it still be group policy? I'm currently looking in to the shell theme service things, but won't really be able to test till Tuesday when I'm back in the office.

Comment: Also, is the service called Themes? I can't find anything called Shell Theme or Windows Shell Theme.

Comment: Yeah, it's just Themes. I couldn't remember the name before.

Comment: Not the Themes service, very annoying that this won't work...